# What IKEA furniture or tools is permitted to be assembled on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, boneh-soter

IKEA offers lots of furniture and utensils for self-assembly, some of which are pretty sophisticated, requiring screws and fasteners and some are pretty easy to assemble without tools or connecting parts.

I take IKEA as they are known for modularity, especially for efficiency in storage. While big furniture is clearly out of question, small or simple items like utensils are tricky, maybe a snap-on handle for a plastic glass or, say, two-piece fork.

In general, what types of those tools/furniture can be constructed on Shabbos?

Comment: Are there specific IKEA tools/methods/parts you have in mind, making this a parallel to questions like [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28337/3) or is this the general question "What types of furniture can be constructed?"?

Comment: @WAF THe linked question looks like a Q. about a tent. And tools/utensils might be different. I took IKEA as they are known for modularity, especially for efficiency in storage. While big furniture is clearly out of question, small items like utensils are tricky, maybe just a handle for a plastic glass or, say, two-piece fork.

Comment: You might do well to specify that. I almost edited into the question that it is not about large furniture, but there's already an answer addressing that exclusively and specifically. . .

Answer (score 3):

R Jack Abramowitz clarifies ([here](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/the-39-melachos/melacha34/)) the distinction between the permitted and forbiddden part of the *melacha* of *boneh* (assembling or building)

> While the av melacha (primary labor) involves both assembling separate
>   pieces into a unified whole and forming a shelter, either activity is
>   prohibited on Shabbos, even if the other is not accomplished.
>   Accordingly, one may not pitch a tent or throw schach on the roof of a
>   Succah (forming a shelter in the absence of assembling pieces).
>   **Likewise, one may not put together pre-fabricated furniture (such as one might get at Ikea), even though doing so does not create a
>   shelter. Even screwing the handle into a broom is assembling and
>   therefore boneh!**
>
> Home repairs are included under the melacha of boneh, as one is not
>   permitted to add to an existing structure on Shabbos. Driving a nail
>   into a wall for a picture hook or laying tile are adding to the
>   building and therefore boneh. It is not boneh, however, when an action
>   reflects an object’s normal mode of use. Therefore, if a sliding door
>   comes off its track, it may be replaced. Similarly, one might replace
>   the spring-operated dispenser that holds a roll of bathroom tissue.
>   [...]
>
> While one may not assemble furniture or other utensils on Shabbos, one
>   may open and close folding objects such as tables, chairs, portacribs
>   and strollers. One may not use an umbrella on Shabbos, however,
>   because it creates a shelter.

(see also [Halachipedia](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Boneh)).

Note that the *melacha* of *makeh b’patish* (rendering something fit for use for the first time, see e.g., [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/the-39-melachos/melacha38/)) is another reason not to build furniture.

**Bottom line: most IKEA furniture cannot be assembled on Shabbat and a *rav* should be asked in specific cases of emergency.**

Comment: Thank you, the answer rules out big furniture or those needing fasterners like screws. I clarified the question a bit toward smaller and simpler tools that not require screws. Would you please elaborate on those.

Comment: @AlBerko "IKEA furniture" is not a halachic category and they sell 1000s of items. I answered the question's first version which speaks of furniture. A glass or fork is not furniture but rather a utensil. In general it is forbidden to assemble those (see Rambam Shabbat 7:6 *Whenever one collects separate entities and bonds them together so that they form a single mass, [the activity] resembles building.*) but it might be different if the utensil existed before Shabbat and you are rebuilding, or if the utensil could be used on its own before (e.g., handle of a glass). Different q though

Comment: @AlBerko you might want to revert question to previous version - and ask a different question if you have specific items in mind

Answer (score 1):

Those Halachot are quite famous, this is where you should start looking:

[טור שיג](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.313.1?lang=he)

> מטה של פרקים, אסור להחזירה ולהדקה, ואם תקע חייב חטאת. ואם היה רפויה
>   מותר לכתחלה...

Tur 313

A bed made of "joints" (parts that are made to disassemble and reassemble): It is forbidden to assemble it (on Shabbat), and if he did he needs [to offer] a sacrifice. And if it's loose [its assembly is] allowed from the get-go.